# printwriter vs outputstream vs outputstreamwriter in java

Tags: java

I'm not sure what the difference is between outputstream vs outputstreamwriter in java. Plus I see some usages Printwriter with these two class together. Are not any of these usable independently?

Comment: OutputStreamWriter is a decorator for an existing OutputStream. It provides convenience methods such as write(String), OutputStream can only write(byte[])

Comment: A Java IO stream deals with bytes; a Reader or Writer deals with chars. PrintWriter simply offers a few handy methods (such as `print`). To fully understand them, read the complete descriptions from the Javadoc of each class.

Comment: The best thing for you to do would be to read the documentation on these classes; It explains plenty. Also, I believe learning to read the documentation is an important tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OutputStream**

`OutputStream` is a stream where you can work on for outputting data to any destination. It has basic functionality and allows only writing bytes to the stream.

**PrintWriter and OutputStreamWriter**

`PrintWriter` and `OutputStreamWriter` are helper that let you act on top of an `OutputStream`. For instance the `PrintWriter` lets you write directly `Strings` to the `OutputStream` so that you don't have to take care of writing the bytes.

Answer (score 1):

An `Outputstream` is an output stream of bytes. For example you can output it to your stdout (the static variable `System.out` returns an `Outputstream` that points to stdout). The `OutputstreamWriter` is a wrapper around the `Outputstream` specifically for character streams encoded in a certain encoding, such as utf-8. It provides utility methods for writing Strings or characters to the output.

Comment: `System.out` is a `PrintStream` which is ultimately an `OutputStream`, but since we're talking about the specifics I figure the distinction is significant.